# View's row style output is NULL, template file not found in ./

Tags: 7, views, theming

I'm theming a block view that displays content that is related to the current node. When I preview the view results they show up fine, but the content doesn't render in my theme.

When I examined more, I noticed the **views-view-unformatted** template renders correctly and contains three `rows` as expected, but each of the `rows` just contains the value NULL.

The theme information tool in Views gives the following error regarding row style output:

> **Row style output:** views-view-fields.tpl.php, views-view-fields--read-next.tpl.php,
>   views-view-fields--default.tpl.php,
>   views-view-fields--default.tpl.php, views-view-fields--block.tpl.php,
>   **views-view-fields--read-next--block.tpl.php (File not found, in folder ./)**

I created the file **views-view-fields--read-next--block.tpl.php** with the following content:

```
<?php foreach ($fields as $id => $field): ?>
    <?php print $field->content; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Unfortunately that did not help. The file is still not found and nothing is rendered. Other things I've tried:

- Disabling devel_themer
- Clearing all caches
- Restarting Apache
- Checking file permissions
- Changing the view formatting back and forth a few times
- **Edit:** Rescanning the template files

What can be the problem? I don't know where to look next. I'm using **Views 7.x-3.10**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out the cause of this - I had previously defined the function `mytheme_views_view_fields__read_next__block()` in **template.php** and forgot to return a value. Views module's theming information gives a confusing error message when templates are defined in **template.php** instead of the **templates** directory.

Answer (score 0):

After creating a new tpl file for views to pick up you need to hit the button called " rescan template files" at the bottom of the window. So that your new tpl gets highlighted.

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to mention I've rescanned the template files a couple of times between each of my solution attempts.